# Getting search rank of freebase topics

Tags: freebase

Is there a way to get the search rank of freebase topics? We want to order the freebase topics in our database according to their search rank and popularity. I know the Metaweb search API returns the topics in the order of search rank but that applies only to the results for a given query string. We want to apply that logic on the topics that exists in our database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Freebase Search API](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/API#Searching_with_Search_API) ranks topics based mostly on keyword matching in the title and the description of a topic with the given search query. To get this same feature in your own database you'll have to write your own search ranking code or use a library like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org).

You might also be interested in [a related discussion](http://markmail.org/message/372w4an2f54rddyi) that happened on the Freebase mailing list last month about how to rank topics based on overall measures of popularity.